# Prefill customer email via Stripe Payment Link URL

Tags: forms, url, attributes, stripe-payments

I'm testing out Stripe's new Payment Links in a project, and I'm trying to prefill a user's email address in the email field of the checkout form. I tried appending the payment link URL with the "email" data attribute, which doesn't work, the data isn't passed on:

```
https://buy.stripe.com/14k...fYZ?email=johnsmith@gmail.com
```

I know Stripe's client-side checkout solution does allow for this, but I'm trying to just use the Payment Link, since it's so much simpler. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: recommend you finalise Arons answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 34):

Update: it looks like this is now possible using URL parameters including `?prefilled_email`. [See documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#url-parameters)

`?prefilled_email` Seems to be working as expected

✅ [stripe.com/docs/payment-links/customer-info](https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/customize#customize-checkout-with-url-parameters)

Comment: Not available anymore unless using Checkout Sessions API. A no-code solution is not available for payment links as of 6/8/23.

Comment: `?prefilled_email` Seems to be working as expected ✅ https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/customer-info

Comment: working for me 7/18/23

Comment: Still working 24-12-2023.

Comment: The docs are here: https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/customize#customize-checkout-with-url-parameters

Comment: How does this work with Stripe Link (prefilled info). Does `prefilled_email` override the Link info or are both passed through in the payment details or the `prefilled_email` email is dropped?

Answer (score 6):

Stripe Payment Links do not support pre-filling the customer's email.

However, if you're comfortable writing some code, you can [use the Stripe API to create a Checkout Session with a pre-filled email](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer_email).  Once you create the session you can [send your customer to the `url` provided in the Checkout Session object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url).

Comment: You can now prefill as so: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#url-prefills

Comment: If you use the API to prefill the email, will the customer still be able to edit their email address on the checkout page?

Answer (score 4):

As of 11th July 2023, Stripe does have [limited support for URL prefills](https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/customer-info#customize-checkout-with-url-parameters).
To explore all the supported values:

- Go to https://dashboard.stripe.com/payment-links/<your_payment_link>
- Click on the dropdown next to the Copy button
- Click on URL parameters and explore away

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass query string params to Stripe payment links but there is a workaround using PriceBlocs payment links which are built on top of Stripe Checkout.

You can pass params for the following Stripe Checkout params:

- [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer)
- [customer_email](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer_email)
- [email](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer_email) *(alias for customer_email)*
- [client_reference_id](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-client_reference_id)

Heres a working demo link with an email param appended. When checkout starts, you'll see the Stripe checkout email field is pre-filled.
https://priceblocs.com/test/links/1owa3UYo-2hKvRIXJEu79?email=someone@email.com

And then they'll get forwarded into the Stripe checkout session call.
That way you'll get the result you want without having to write any backend code.

Docs for payment links are [here.](https://priceblocs.com/learn/payment-links/attribution#query-string-params)

API docs are [here.](https://priceblocs.com/docs/payments/payment-links/create)

And there's a link builder playground [here.](https://priceblocs.com/features/links/builder)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! I tried priceblocs after reading this post and I've loved it ever since. I've had great interactions with the founder who answers the live chat personally. He's brilliant, thorough, and most importantly, Priceblocs works great. It has a really good integration with Zapier too, which means I can take the data from checkout events and pip it into airtable and other stuff. I'm using priceblocs for the signup part of https://mtilive.io. Priceblocs lets me sell a stripe product as a subscription with a trial period, with no coding. Priceblocs absolutely rocks!!

Comment: Seems like you can prefill info: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#url-prefills

Comment: I don't think this is valid anymore. As of 6/8/23, I cannot find this information in the docs.